# Reduce multiple br tags using regex in JavaScript

Tags: php, regex, xml

There's a whole bunch of questions on SO regarding regex and br tags; unfortunately, none of them address this scenario. Yes, I do need to look for every occurrence of more than 2 `<br>`'s without any text in between and reduce them the just 2. However, the tags in my case are not always technically consecutive. There could be other opening/closing tags in between them. Here's an example:

```
<xyz>
<abc>blah blah blah</abc>
<br>
</xyz>
<br>
<br>
<ynt>
<br>
<abc>some more text here</abc>
```

In this example, although there's no point where more than two `<br>` tags appear consecutively, there still remains the effect of 4 consecutive `<br>` tags when rendered in the browser. This is the kind of situation I'm looking to address. I would love to try out something but have no clue where to even start! How can one mark an indefinite number of tags between two `<br>` tags while leaving out any non-tag text? Am not asking to be hand-fed...just a hint in the right direction would be great.

In an attempt to simplify the process, I tried to handle this at the server by removing all instances of `<br>` from the text right in the PHP used to retrieve the XML. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

// This function grabs the definition of a word in XML format.
function grab_xml_definition ($word, $ref, $key)
    {   $uri = "http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/" . urlencode($ref) . "/xml/" . 
                    urlencode($word) . "?key=" . urlencode($key);
        return readfile($uri);
    };

$xdef = grab_xml_definition($_POST['lookup_word'], "spanish", "6d4d41f9-c28f-4544-9bb3-1b4708d1a4d1");
$xdef = str_ireplace("<br>", "", $xdef);
echo $xdef;

?>
```

I have used a simple `str_ireplace()` for the job; however, the tags remain unchanged. Even a `preg_replace("#<br>#", "", $xdef);` didn't do the trick!

PS: Just tried `strip_tags($xdef,"<br>");` in my PHP and still failed to get rid of the tags.

Comment: It's going to be a little hard, you have to figure out what tags have visible content, where the content is, and how the breaks play into that etc.

Comment: @adeneo What if I tried to run a JQuery replace() on text() instead of html() and just looked for all \n's replacing 3 or more consecutive occurrences of \n with just 2? If at all that's a workable hack, how do I specify in the regex that it has to match only for more than 2 consecutive `\n`'s?

Comment: @TheLearner that won't do you any good, as `.text()` won't give you back any elements, just text node content. You'll have to write some sort of DOM traversal code that maintains some state as it goes through the tree. Seems kind-of non-trivial to me, and personally I'd try to focus my energy on avoiding the unwanted `<br>` tags in the first place.

Comment: I would love to have avoided the excessive <br> mess at the server level but the tags come along with the xml I'm trying to parse and the parser I have written in PHP is refusing to cooperate. :(

Comment: What Pointy said, you can use `text()` to get the text and replace newlines, but you probably want to put the content back in the DOM, and you've just lost all the markup and the elements, and are left with just text, which is probably not at all what you want. I too would try to stick with DOM methods and nodes, it's just easier to work with in cases like this.

Comment: @adeneo I tried handling this at the server end to completely eliminate the messy <br> situation altogether. Unfortunately, nothing I tried there seems to work either. I have updated the question with my server-side PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the server code. From the PHP manual on `readfile`: *Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer. [...] Returns the number of bytes read from the file.*

You are storing the XML's length in $xdef, not the string content. Use `file_get_contents` instead of `readfile` and you'll be fine. No use for (indeed very complicated) client-side corrections.

Comment: Problem is, if I use `file_get_contents` instead of `readfile`, I lose all tags whatsoever which is a disaster because I need those tags in order to parse out the content. All I need to get rid of is the `<br>` tag. Funny enough, although all tags vanish when I use `file_get_contents`, a whole bunch of `<br>`'s still slip through!

Comment: @TheLearner: This is not what I see when testing your PHP code posted above. I replaced the $_POST variable with a more or less random string (in this case 'maduro'), and replaced `readfile` with `file_get_contents`. `$xdef` is then filled with text, including a bunch of <example>, <antonym> and <synonym> tags.

You should read up on your PHP, especially the `strip_tags` page. You're using the second parameter in the wrong way.

Comment: Accepting my answer wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Like I said, running the exact same code (the PHP I have mentioned in the question) with `file_get_contents` instead of `readfile` is NOT removing all `<br>` tags. I would accept your answer but doing so would imply the issue is resolved which is not the case. And I don't see anything wrong with my `strip_tags` syntax. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @TheLearner: Like I said, read up on your PHP. `strip_tags` removes all tags *except* the ones in the second argument. That's why you are losing all other tags. Stick with you initial approach (i.e. str_replace) and use `file_get_contents()`.